# Ubuntu 16.04.1suspend

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I got a problem with my ubuntu 16.04.1 OS. 
It does not go to suspend state after closing the lid. 
I have already selected it to suspend when the lid is closed in 
System settings > power

Please help me to fix this bug.

Thank You.